# How do you trigger the '&' isolate scope from a child components controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Question:**  From the child components controller how would I trigger an event as the `refresh: '&'` binding view e.g. `ng-click="$ctrl.refresh()'`?

*Typically I would have an ng-click liek so:*

**Module:**

```
module.component('childComponent', {
  template: template,
  controller: Controller,
  bindings: {refresh: '&'}
});
```

**CHILD COMPONENT HTML:**

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.refresh()">
  Approve
</button>
```

**PARENT COMPONENT HTML:**

```
<child-component refresh='$ctrl.doSomething()'></child-component>
```

*Now I need to call it from the ctrl as I'm waiting for a response from a promise.*

**WHAT I NEED:**

**Child Controller**

```
 submit() {

    this.service.putData(this.data)
        .then((res) => {
             this.refresh() // EVENT WOULD GO HERE RIGHT HERE
        });
  }
```

**Child Template:**

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.submit()">
  Approve
</button>
```

Comment: It should work, what is the problem?

Comment: Shit :( sorry This was theory code.  I just assumed you needed to create some kind of eventEmitter